# Regression Mode evaluation

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-mining

I'm searching for method to evaluate a regression models like the accuracy in clustering models, please could you tell me how I can evaluate my regression model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple: I assume your regression function spits out a number which is somewhat different from your target value. It might even be simpler than clustering, let me explain why...

**Difference in evaluation**

In Clustering you have labels. An element can have the wrong or the correct label. There are different cases (false positive, false negative, true positive, true negative). Your test might need to consider all these cases (accuracy looks at the overall correctness, no matter what).

In regression your result is a number (like 2.123) and your target is another number (like 1.100). Your error is the difference (in thise case 1.023). You can now apply various different ways to calculate how big your error is across all results, also considergin positive and negative error.

**Ways to calculate**

There are plenty of ways and you need to pick what is right for you. Here are the two probably most popular ones:

- Sum of squared errors (SSE): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares
- Mean sqwuared error (MSE): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error

Comment: thank you for your replying, Great explain,,,,

I applied the metric you mentioned above to my model and it gives me 0.0000453861
and I applied the R squared metric to the same model and it gives me
0.321107000102

I'm confused about the difference between results of two metrics, why there is that huge difference in number?

Comment: It is hard to make general statements without looking at the data. To apply those metrics you need to understand how they work in order to interpret them. For example while R Squared (good idea by the way!) is a relative metric that tells you a percentage value between 0 and 1, SSE gives you an absolute value. I think you need to invest some time reading up metrics. There are good explanations like this one online: http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/regression-analysis-how-do-i-interpret-r-squared-and-assess-the-goodness-of-fit